# Merge content if same variable(email)

Tags: php

I have code below to select events,users and subusers and send email to user if there is new event that subuser created.

```
$result_m = mysqli_query($db, $query_mail) or die(mysqli_error());

while ($re4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_m, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
    $ajdi = $re4["pid"];
    $name1 = $re4["name"];
    $surname1 = $re4["surname"];
    $email1 = $re4["email"];
    $mob = $re4["mob"];
    $titl1 = $re4["title"];
    $zip1 = $re4["zip"];
    $city1 = $re4["city"];
    $address1 = $re4["address"];
    $insurance1 = $re4["insurance"];
    $born1 = $re4["born"];
    $receiver = $re4["demail"];
    $content= "<p><img src='$logo'></p>";
    $content.= "<p><br/>Name: $name1 $surname1, Born: $born1, Insurance: $insurance1<br/>$address1, $city1 $zip1, Tel: $mob, Email: $email1</p>";
    $title= "Mail title";
    $content.= "<p>Footer message</p>";
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
    $headers[] = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
    $headers[] = "From: no-reply@test.com";
    if ($receiver!= "")
        {
        mail($receiver, $title, $content, implode("\r\n", $headers));
        }
    }
```

This is also wrapped in another while loop that gets all events.
With this user gets email when subuser creates event but he gets email for every event if there is more of them.
How to send just one email to user with all created events in it?

For example, when I do `echo "$receiver<br>$content<br>";` I get:

```
email@email.com
Some content
email@email.com
Some content2
email2@email.com
Some content
email2@email.com
Some content2
```

But I need it like this:

```
email@email.com
Some content
Some content2
email2@email.com
Some content
Some content2
```

How to achieve this? Thank you

UPDATE (array according to Erwin Moller answer)

```
Array
(
    [mail1@email.com] => 
22.07.2015., 08:30 Uhr
)
Array
(
    [mail1@email.com] => 
23.07.2015., 08:15 Uhr
)
Array
(
    [mail1@email.com] => 
09.09.2015., 14:45 Uhr
)
Array
(
    [mail1@email.com] => 
03.08.2015., 14:40 Uhr
)
Array
(
    [mail1@email.com] => 
03.08.2015., 11:40 Uhr
)
Array
(
    [mail1@email.com] => 
03.08.2015., 14:20 Uhr
)
Array
(
    [mail2@email.com] => 
30.07.2015., 15:40 Uhr
)
Array
(
    [mail2@email.com] => 
24.07.2015., 14:00 Uhr
)
Array
(
    [mail3@email.com] => 
24.07.2015., 14:00 Uhr
)
Array
(
    [mail3@email.com] => 
30.07.2015., 15:40 Uhr
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approach this in a few ways.

One simple way is this:
Do not send the emails, but first store them all in an array, using the emailaddress as the key.

Something like this:

```
... db stuff
$allRecipients = array();
while ($re4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_m, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $ajdi = $re4["pid"];
    $name1 = $re4["name"];
    $surname1 = $re4["surname"];
    $email1 = $re4["email"];
    $mob = $re4["mob"];
    $titl1 = $re4["title"];
    $zip1 = $re4["zip"];
    $city1 = $re4["city"];
    $address1 = $re4["address"];
    $insurance1 = $re4["insurance"];
    $born1 = $re4["born"];
    $receiver = $re4["demail"];
    $content= "<p><img src='$logo'></p>";
    $content.= "<p><br/>Name: $name1 $surname1, Born: $born1, Insurance: $insurance1<br/>$address1, $city1 $zip1, Tel: $mob, Email: $email1</p>";
    if ($receiver!= ""){
            if (isset($allRecipients[$receiver]){
                // add the content.
                $allRecipients[$receiver] .= "<hr>".$content;
            } else {
                $allRecipients[$receiver] = $content;
            }        
    }
}

// now mail
$title= "Mail title";
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
$headers[] = "From: no-reply@test.com";
// If you are curious how that array looks, add this:
// echo "<pre>";
// print_r($allRecipients);
// echo "</pre>";

foreach ($allRecipients as $receiver => $content){
    $content.= "<p>Footer message</p>";
    mail($receiver, $title, $content, implode("\r\n", $headers));       
}
```

Comment: sidenote: OP is using `MYSQL_ASSOC` which should be `MYSQLI_ASSOC` with the added "I". You copied the same code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks, I indeed copied it blindly because I focussed on the array-email-as-key trick. ;-) Fixed now.

Comment: @ErwinMoller thanks for answer but with this I get same result. It sends mail for each receiver no matter if email is same

Comment: Uncomment this:echo "<pre>";
print_r($allRecipients);
echo "</pre>";
WHat is in the array???

Comment: @ErwinMoller I get `Array([test@email.com] => <p><img src='logourl'></p><p>content</p>)` and another one for other event with that email

Comment: could you maybe append the output (formatted in a code-block for readability) under your original posting?

Comment: @ErwinMoller I added array. So in it all dates that correspond to same email shold be grouped and send to that email once, not for every date another email.

Comment: You must have done something different. Please doublecheck if you added the code right I posted that starts with: if ($receiver!= ""){

Comment: @ErwinMoller I set that if but it is inside while loop where every event has its email so I don't know why would that make a difference. I set it in original code just because some events didn't had email so I wanted to avoid them.

Comment: You must not have copied my example code right, otherwise you couldn't end up with the same keys in $allRecipients....

Comment: Problem was another while loop that was wrapped around this.. I changed that and it works now. Just a note.. closing bracket is missing for isset in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem can be solved by
adding `GROUP BY` in your select query and merge all the content
i.e  `SELECT email,"Merged Content" FROM your_table_name GROUP BY email`
Note :- this Merged Content You have to format according to your requirement

Then just iterate through query result and send email's :)